# Cannot open react-native app in Expo Go app

Tags: react-native, expo

After I publish my react-native app with `expo-cli publish` I get the following result:

```
› Expo SDK: 38.0.0
› Release channel: default
› Workflow: Bare

- Optimization: Project may contain uncompressed images. Optimizing image assets can improve app size and performance.
  To fix this, run npx expo-optimize. Learn more: https://docs.expo.io/distribution/optimizing-updates/#optimize-images

Building optimized bundles and generating sourcemaps...
Starting Metro Bundler
Building iOS bundle
Building Android bundle
Finished building JavaScript bundle in 13254ms.
Building source maps
Finished building JavaScript bundle in 8302ms.
Finished building JavaScript bundle in 115ms.
Building asset maps
Finished building JavaScript bundle in 103ms.
Finished building JavaScript bundle in 385ms.
Finished building JavaScript bundle in 333ms.

Bundle                     Size
┌ index.ios.js          1.07 MB
├ index.android.js      1.08 MB
├ index.ios.js.map      4.07 MB
└ index.android.js.map   4.1 MB

 JavaScript bundle sizes affect startup time. Learn more: https://expo.fyi/javascript-bundle-sizes

Analyzing assets
Saving assets
No assets changed, skipped.

Uploading JavaScript bundles
Publish complete
```

When I go on my Expo Go app and then open the app, I see the following error message:

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2JQK5.png)

I couldn't find anyone having the same issue. Why do I get this error message?

**Diagnostic:**

```
Expo CLI 4.5.0 environment info:
    System:
      OS: macOS 11.3.1
      Shell: 5.8 - /bin/zsh
    Binaries:
      Node: 12.14.1 - /usr/local/bin/node
      npm: 6.13.4 - /usr/local/bin/npm
    Managers:
      CocoaPods: 1.10.1 - /usr/local/bin/pod
    SDKs:
      iOS SDK:
        Platforms: iOS 14.4, DriverKit 20.2, macOS 11.1, tvOS 14.3, watchOS 7.2
    IDEs:
      Xcode: 12.4/12D4e - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
    npmPackages:
      react: 17.0.1 => 17.0.1 
      react-dom: ^17.0.2 => 17.0.2 
      react-native: 0.64.1 => 0.64.1 
      react-native-web: ^0.16.3 => 0.16.3 
      react-navigation: ^4.4.4 => 4.4.4 
    npmGlobalPackages:
      expo-cli: 4.5.0
    Expo Workflow: bare
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I am in a situation like you, I start commenting out code. Begin at the root of your app, comment out half of it and check wheter the problem exists. If it still occurs, comment out the other half and drill down the code-tree.

Comment: I should have added that the app is running on my laptop inside the simulator, without errors.